# Server that responds to particular HTTP POST requests in C#

Tags: c#, http, post

I was wondering if there is a way to code a HTTP Server in C# that responds to particular POST requests ?
Like, a client sends to "http://127.0.0.1/Bob/hello" something like `{"name":"Bob", "working":"true"}` in a POST request and the server responds specificly to him "Ok bob, everything is fine, can you go check the "Windows" folder please ?" and will respond something for `{"name":"Eva", "working":"false"}` in "http://127.0.0.1/Eva/hello".
Is it possible do to something like that and if yes, how ? Thanks.

Comment: You're asking it as a general question for handling requests in an ASP.NET WebApi website ? or just this specific `/Bob/hello` path + post data as part of a very very lightweight http server ?

Comment: @OrelEraki, just the specific /Bob/hello path